# If $a \in X$ we can say "$X$ contains $a$". Is there a corresponding verb for the relation $A \subset X$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Obviously I can say "$X$ has $A$ as a subset" or "$A$ is a subset of $X$", but I'd like a more concise way of putting this.

Comment: "$A$ is *part* of $X$", compared to "$a$ is *element* of $X$".

Comment: Also, "$A$ is [*included*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) in $B$".

Comment: The word 'contains' is ambiguous in the first place—you could also say '$X$ contains $A$' to mean $A \subseteq X$. If it's not clear from context whether 'contains' means $\ni$ or $\supseteq$, you could add '... as an element' or '... as a subset' to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

$A \subset X$ translates to A is subset of X. You can say that A is included in B, as @Mauro said in the comment.

Moreover you can say, every element in set A is present in set X. This is **one** of the most mathematically true statement you can say for $A \subset X$.

Mathematically representing, $\forall x $ | $ x \in A \implies x \in X $